# Count cells containing a value and that value is in other range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, contains, worksheet-function

I have a list like this:

[image]

I want to count the  names (column B) that have value in column A like a or b or ...  also this pair value is in range (F,G columns) .

How to do it?

For example:
count of b mark values is 4, but I am trying to count b mark except (b reza) , because the b reza is in the range F,G;

Count of b is 3.
Count of b (special b) is 1.

Comment: What are you trying to count? The pairs over in F/G?  `=COUNTIFS(A1:A8,F1,B1:B8,G1)`?

Comment: count the "b" mark values where they are in the other range.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I want count pairs that first is "b" and this pairs not in G  or count if in G.

Comment: so like (count if b) - (count if b and name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do below things after trying more.

[image]

in the H column i use this formula :

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A;F1;$B:$B;G1)>0
```

in row 2  :

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A;F2;$B:$B;G2)>0
```

and copy this formula in all;
This formula give me (if the result is TRUE) that current row of G,H List is in A,B list.
Count of the TRUE values are the spacial values that i call them الف .
I can count all special data in A,B list (20):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A;"a")+COUNTIF(A:A;"b")+COUNTIF(A:A;"c")
```

The count of special values that not in F,G list is 20-6=14 i call them ب.

this is what i want. but perhaps this is not good method. any idea?

Comment: And why exactly do you think that your method is not good? You get the value you need. Why is it not good?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to enter Array formulas?

**First formula:**

```
=SUM((A1:A8=F$2)*(B1:B8=G$2))
```

Enter it as array formula (press **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter**). After hitting the keys the formula will be embraced in curly braces { }. This formula will give you the result of `1`.

**Second formula:**

```
=SUM((A1:A8=F$2)*(B1:B8<>G$2))
```

This is also an array formula. It gives the result of `3`.

Comment: thank you.the result is true. if we have more data(A:B) and some of them is in list F:G  list how can we check(in counting formula).?

Comment: If you want to see the result for both, _a habib_ and _b reza_, then you will need to expand the formula in order to check one additional person. We will build on the 1st formula, which counts occurencies (result of `1` in the answer). Expand the formula like this: `=SUM((A1:A8=F$1)*(B1:B8=G$1),(A1:A8=F$2)*(B1:B8=G$2))`. Note that one additional component was added (checking for _a habib_). Everything else remains the same. The result now is `2`. There is no other (simplier) method using worksheet formulas. Or at least I am not aware of it.